# How can I convert a part of Java source file to Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

In my Kotlin project, I have some parts of Java code that I want to convert to Kotlin. The menu item that converts the Java file to Kotlin is disabled because it's not a whole file I want to convert.

How can I convert Java code to Kotlin?

Comment: Do you want to convert Java code to Kotlin or Kotlin code to Java?

Comment: CMD+SHFT+ALT+K is the easiest way to convert from Java to Kotlin in Android Studio

Comment: Used the following tool to convert some complex java code to kotlin - https://www.javainuse.com/java2kot

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There is no tool to convert Kotlin code to Java. If you want to convert part of a file from Java to Kotlin, the easiest way is to copy the code from the Java file in the IDE and paste it into the Kotlin file.

Comment: This is true within Intellij IDEA, the auto-convert Java to Kotlin.  Does it also work with the Eclipse plugin for Kotlin?

Comment: @yole, any chance to see "Paste and convert Java to Kotlin" action in IDEA/AS? I was discouraged that prompt "Convert to Kotlin?" is not predictable when I'm trying to paste Java code – I thought some code analysis is used to detect Java code in clipboard :) The answers here enlightened me. But an issue still here – I have to use .java file as intermediate if I'm copying from the browser.

Comment: Actually, there is such a tool. https://try.kotlinlang.org/ has a convert from Java dialog where you can paste your code in and get Kotlin code out.

Comment: Shift + Alt + Ctrl + k in Windows worked for me in Android studio so please check once

Comment: @2xsaiko I did not find that option though. Where is it?

Comment: This worked for a couple of times (pasting an entire file), but does not work for snippets, not even simple ones. It seems to always have to be a functional and complete activity or class to do anything. Tried pasting a syntax correct Java snippet into a .java file and use the menu action (Code > Convert etc), were warned, and the result of the conversion was an empty file...

Answer (score 144):

### With Android Studio 3.0

You **don't need to install** any plugin to convert java code to kotlin code. Now, Google is **officially supporting** Kotlin language.

- Android Studio Menu -> **Code -> Convert Java File to Kotlin File**

### Before Android Studio 3.0

If you are using older Android Studio ( which is below version 3.0 ) there is a **Kotlin tool** under the menu.

Installing Kotlin plugin :

- Android Studio Menu -> **File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Browse repositories -> Kotlin**

Converting Java Code to Kotlin Code :

- Select your java class file from project structure.
- Android Studio Menu -> **Code -> Convert Java File to Kotlin File**

Comment: But is this possible to for all java files convert to kt files?

Comment: It is possible as I know. And even when you can copy java code and paste it to the **.kt** file. Android Studio will ask you to "Would you like to convert java code to kotlin code" option.

Comment: I do not have this as an option what do I do?

Comment: @WilliamA, probably this is because it wants to convert a whole file, not a piece of code. You can use https://try.kotlinlang.org/ ("Convert from Java" button), as wrote Md Mohsin.

Answer (score 29):

I found a workaround:

1. Create a Java file and paste inside this file Java code, which you want to convert.
2. Now copy Java code from Java file.
3. Go to the Kotlin file and paste this code. IDEA will suggest convert code from Java to Kotlin.

Answer (score 26):

To convert Java code in Android studio use CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+K

To convert from Website use [Try Kotlin](https://try.kotlinlang.org/) site.

To convert from Android app use [Master in Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=coders.hub.android.master&hl=en).

Comment: Can't find this functionality on the Try Kotlin site. Do you have a direct link?

Comment: @pasio They have changed the interface of the website and remove conversion now. Need to check properly that they are providing convertor or not!

Answer (score 24):

To convert a complete file into Kotlin, use this combo of keys:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> in
  Mac
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +
  <kbd>k</kbd> in Windows

Comment: how to do this in an exact opposition manner. Kotlin -> Java ?

Comment: @KamleshKarwande, it is impossible. I was interested in it, JetBrains won't write such a tool.

Comment: Maybe for a whole file, I don't know, but a fragment is not converted anymore. AS 3.5.3, Windows.

Answer (score 11):

When pasting Java code into Kotlin file, using IntelliJ derived IDE, the IDE will not convert the Java into Kotlin.

The problem seems to stem from IntelliJ not knowing the code is Java. Here is a simple way to ensure that code is converted into Kotlin.

1. Copy the Java code from your web browser.
2. Open Scratch File (File -> New -> Scratch File or Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Insert)
3. In the Languages dialog select Java as the language.

[image: New Scratch window Languages dialog.]

4. Paste the previously copied Java snippet.
5. Select All (Ctrl-A) and Copy (Ctrl-C)
6. Now Paste into your Kotlin code.

By first pasting the Java code into a Java scratch file, you have let IntelliJ know that the code snippet is Java code. It will then automatically convert the code to Kotlin when pasting into a Kotlin file.

Comment: On Intellij Ultimate 2017.02 on OS X, when I do the paste, I get the dialog, and when I select "yes" to do the conversion, the resulting file is blank. When I choose "no" it pastes it as Java code. So it seems buggy/broken.

Answer (score 11):

**In Android Studio 3.0**

Kotlin is fully supported from **Android Studio 3.0** (i.e, NO Kotlin Plugin required). If you have Android Studio **>= 3.0** then your following jobs are very easy,

- You can create new Kotlin file.
- You can add Kotlin code to existing
  Project.
- You can convert entire JAVA code into Kotlin

**Convert existing Java code to Kotlin code**

In Android Studio 3.0, open a Java file and select **Code > Convert Java File to Kotlin File.**

Or, create a new Kotlin file **(File > New > Kotlin File/Class)**, and then paste your Java code into that file—when prompted, click **Yes** to convert the code to Kotlin. You can check **Don't show this dialog next time**, which makes it easy to dump Java code snippets into your Kotlin files.

**Dialog Window**

[image]

[*Official Source :: Convert to Kotlin From JAVA*](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/get-started.html#convert-to-kotlin-code)

**Note::When you create a new project**

Tick checkbox **Include Kotlin support** to get kotlin support for the entire project.

The below is the screen shot of first screen of new Android Project Creation Window with an option to include Kotlin Support to the entire project.

[image: Create new Android project with Kotlin support]

Answer (score 10):

Simple Ctrl+Alt+Shift+ K code will convert into kotlin

Answer (score 4):

[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14UO1.png)

In Android 3.0 Canary, it is very simple: Go to Code; the last option is 'Convert Java file into Kotlin.' And you are done!

There is also a shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+Shift+K

Answer (score 4):

its a simple process..
go into your Android studio's tool bar and Do follow this Step

CODE -> Convert java file to kotlin file..

then it asks you for Confirmation and Restart the Android Studio IDE..when you confirm then it restart your IDE and it show you converted Kotlin code file...

Answer (score 3):

If your Android Studio version is less than 3 then you have to install plugin of Kotlin. To install it follow steps from below link

[Blog jetbrains :- Working with Kotlin in Android Studio](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2013/08/working-with-kotlin-in-android-studio/)

After installing plugin restart Android Studio and Find Action (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and type Convert Java File to Kotlin.

Answer (score 3):

From kotlinlang.org, [click on "Try Online" at the top of the page](https://try.kotlinlang.org/). You'll see an option to "Convert from Java" in the toolbar.

[image: Click Try Online]

[image: Click Convert from Java]

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any specific tools. Just simply copy and paste from anywhere and paste to `.kt` file in `Android Studio.` Dialog Window will be open by asking "Convert `Java to Kotlin`". Press Yes, It will convert it and do some miner changes.

Answer (score 2):

In the new Android Studio version of 4.1 and above, you don't have to do any of the above stuff. You simply copy and paste any Java code into any existing kt file in Android Studio and it will recognize it as Java code needed to be converted to Kotlin. Then it will ask you in a dialog box whether it's something you want to do and convert it right in the spot if you answer yes. You can also check the "do not ask to convert" and it will automatically convert any Java code you paste in the future for you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this -

1. Copy the code from the .java file.
2. Create a new file with .kt extension.
3. Paste the code.
4. A pop up would appear asking to convert the code you pasted to Kotlin. Allow.