# IntelliJ's IdeaVim plugin disables converting Java to Kotlin

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, ideavim

I would like to use IntelliJ's feature, which converts Java code to Kotlin by simply copy-pasting from Java file to Kotlin file. It is working fine, but when I turn on IdeaVim plugin, it refuses to work anymore. I know Vim decently and I that's not the problem with my misunderstanding Vim edit modes. I am aware of [How can I convert a part of Java source file to Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588117/how-can-i-convert-a-part-of-java-source-file-to-kotlin) and answer by @yole saying that there is no other tool to do that.

But that answer was made over 3 months ago, and maybe some other tool appeared. So, my question is if someone found workaround to make IdeaVim plugin cooperate with Java to Kotlin conversion. I've already made a ticket on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1103 but frankly, I am not so sure if it will be resolved.

Comment: The issue is fixed with the latest version of IdeaVim (0.53+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, guy from JetBrains answered my issue. The obvious workaround (which I didn't figure out) is to **copy and paste from context menu**. Then conversion question shows up. IMO it seems unlikely that IdeaVim plugin will support this feature by yanking and putting (Vim's copying and pasting), as from:

> Running IDE actions on copy and paste might be a good idea, but we're not sure it wouldn't disrupt the workflow of the current users.

Comment: As I wrote above: map the `EditorPast` action to your favorite shortcut or let IDEA handle the `<C-v>` shortcut.

Comment: But <C-v> didn't work because Vim plugin somehow overintercepts pasting and typical Vim shortcut 'p' pastes text, I may try remapping `EditorPaste` though.

Comment: See my last edit. There is a setting to define which handler should handle a certain action.

Answer (score 1):

The vim plugin takes over the clipboard and past functions. When you type `:actionlist` you get a list of idea actions you can use in your `.ideavimrc` file to map keymaps to idea actions. Use `:action COMMAND` to execute the command.

I.e.:

`norepmap <C-w>q :action VimWindowClose<cr>`

closes the current window.

Furthermore, you can search for a particular `action` with `:actionlist Past`. 
This lists

`EditorPast  <C-V> <S-ins>`

among other things.

If you want to check if `EditorPast` ist the right command you can test it using `:action EditorPaste`.

Another way to make this work is to let idea handle the `<C-v>` shortcut. This can be archieved with the `Settings -> Other Setting -> Vim Emulation` settings. The handler (vim or idea) can be defined with that setting.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but when I type `:actionList` I get message from IDE (on bottom bar) saying 'VIM - Not an editor command: actionList'

Comment: Try `:actionlist` .. not `:actionList`

Comment: `:actionlist` is ok :) I'll dive into that command and its possibilities soon, but I think it isn't the problem. I **can** do copy-paste and I do, but the problem lays not i Vim command itself, but in IDE (or IDE's plugin) behavior, that's how I see it.