# Converting code from Java to Kotlin in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, screen-orientation

Can anyone explain how to replace existing Java code with Kotlin within Android Studio?

Comment: If you are using android studio (3.0 +), go to `Code` -> `Convert Java File to Kotlin File`, or simply copy-paste the code in a kotlin file

Comment: Currently copy-paste often doesn't convert.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588117/how-can-i-convert-a-part-of-java-source-file-to-kotlin.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47125184/6723193) out.

Answer (score 16):

If you've got Kotlin already configured in your Android Studio project, you can follow the steps outlined here to automatically convert with the instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/converting-a-java-file-to-kotlin-file.html).

From the site:

- On the main menu, point to Code menu.
- Choose Convert Java File to Kotlin File.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using **android studio 3.5+**, Just select your java file from your package, right click on it and select **Convert Java file to Kotlin file** from the bottom of popup menu

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert a code block and not a whole file, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43308666/1831722) (TL;DR using a Java scratch file let's your code be interpreted as such by the IDE and when pasting will trigger the *Do you want to convert to Kotlin?* pop-up).