# Convert java to kotlin on paste

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

So I checked "Don't show this dialog next time", but it turns out that it will then never convert the code again.

Where do I remove the checkmark again so I can get back to converting the java code to kotlin when pasted?

Thanks in advance.

https://developer.android.com/kotlin/get-started.html#convert-to-kotlin-code

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys -> Convert pasted Java code to Kotlin (at the end of the page)

Comment: Turns out i must have clicked no since only the last option is checked. Works - thanks!

Comment: Now under File->Settings->Editor->General->Smart Keys-> etc

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to have the "Do you want to convert ..." dialog again, despite the option to convert checked.

1. Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys -> Scroll to the end -> Convert posted Java code to Kotlin (checked)
2. Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys -> Scroll to the end -> Don't show Java to Kotlin conversion dialog on paste (unchecked)
3. File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart