# How to convert kotlin code into android java code without decompilation of kotlin byte code because that will not return android java code

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I can easly convert java code into kotlin in android studio3.0
but can any help to convert it again into android java code.

Comment: Only by hand. Can you explain *why* do you want this? What's the motivation?

Comment: You can find your answer: [ here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588117/how-can-i-convert-a-part-of-java-source-file-to-kotlin)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a kotlin source file to a java source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957430/how-to-convert-a-kotlin-source-file-to-a-java-source-file)

Comment: something funny is how android underestimated the unification java-only-time brought... now you have to garbage yourself with more and more programming languages at the same time competing to have a good grasp at all the langs... This obviously strains developers. If only they could provide a way to translate kotlin to java... and funny how java to kotlin is feasible yet the reverse MUST involve decompiling...

Answer (score 1):

in IntelliJ or Android Studio, you just have to do the following to get java code from kotlin:

1. Menu > Tools > Kotlin > Show Kotlin Bytecode
2. Click on the Decompile button
3. Copy the java code

Comment: But that will not show android Java code that is different