# Java to kotlin conversion specific to my code

Tags: android, kotlin

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b1 =findViewById(R.id.B1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }
```

my question is how to convert this to kotlin and I am new to kotlin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a part of Java source file to Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588117/how-can-i-convert-a-part-of-java-source-file-to-kotlin)

Comment: seeing your comments on the other answers, you should rather have asked how to solve the warning/error regarding the line `Button b1=findViewById(R.id.B1)` (or open a new question for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Ctrl + Alt + Shift + K** shortcut to convert current opened Java class. (Or Android Studio > Code > Convert Java file to Kotlin)
- Or if you **paste** this code into a **kotlin class**, then **Android Studio ask you to convert** code.

These two options make my work done always. I did not need to convert from external website.

Comment: val b1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.B1)   shows redline in the <Button> line

Comment: Kotlin refers views directly by its id, so remove this, use just id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Android to Kotlin [Code Converter](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-kotlin#convert-to-kotlin-code).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from your Java class like below
Select Code from Top Menu in Android Studio

> Code->Convert Java File to Kotlin File

Comment: class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val b1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.B1)
        b1.setOnClickListener {
            val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, Second::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
        }
    }
}                                                                                                                             
        now it is showing redline in button

Comment: @BHARATHWAJ This is how your Java file turned into .kt file

Comment: val b1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.B1)   shows redline in the <Button> line how to fix that

Comment: Try removing <Button>

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you don't need `findViewById` when you want to refer to a view by its id.  
If this is the problem: `Button b1 =findViewById (R.id.B1);` then remove this line.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to convert just 1 code you can go to this link and select the convert from java button

https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Introduction/Java%20to%20Kotlin%20conversion/Task.kt