# How to create objects of a class in kotlin and pass values to it similar to java

Tags: android, kotlin

### What is the equivalent code in `kotlin`

***I am trying to learn***

- How to declare objects of a class
- How to pass values to a new object

**TestClass.java**

```
public class TestClass {


    public TestClass(String hi) {
        Log.d("check","Constructor invocation"+hi);
    }

    public void initiate() {
        Log.d("check","Function invocation");

    }

}
```

**RunningClass.java**

```
public class RunningClass {

    public RunningClass() {

        TestClass mObj = new TestClass("HI");
        mObj.initiate();
    }
}
```

What is the equivalent code of `RunningClass.java` and `TestClass.java` in kotlin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588117/how-can-i-convert-a-part-of-java-source-file-to-kotlin

Comment: When you used "convert Java code to Kotlin" command in IntelliJ, what did you get?

Comment: please don't ask the questions as basic as they are answered in any basic kotlin tutorial. Check some tutorial instead.

Comment: Why not start with the official kotlin docs? There is even "Object oriented Hello" directly at https://kotl.in page which basically solves this whole question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
class TestClass(hi: String) {

    val firstProperty = "First property: $hi".also(::println)

    fun initiate() {
        Log.d("check", "Function invocation")

    }
}
```

> RunningClass.kt

```
class RunningClass {

    constructor () {
        val mObj = TestClass("HI")
        mObj.initiate()
    }
}
```

For more information please read

- [**`Constructors in kotlin`**](https://www.callicoder.com/kotlin-classes-objects-constructors-initializers/#constructors)
- [**`Constructors in kotlin`**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors)
- [**`Kotlin Constructor`**](https://www.journaldev.com/18491/kotlin-class-constructor)
- [**`Kotlin - Constructors`**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/kotlin/kotlin_constructors.htm)

Comment: Imho this is not very beginner-friendly answer, as you use `also`, you do not mention init block, you declare `firstProperty` which is not the part of the original java code and you declare inly to print it, which is basically useless. Also, in `RunningClass` I guess no one declares no-arg constructor like that, when you can use primary constructor, which is auto-declared while declaring the class, together with the init block. Answer proposed by @Mittal Varsani is far more accurate and Kotlin friendly in terms of using code conventions.

Answer (score 2):

TestClass.kt

```
class TestClass(hi: String) {


        init {
            Log.d("check", "Constructor invocation$hi")
        }

        fun initiate() {
            Log.d("check", "Function invocation")

        }

    }
```

RunningClass.kt

```
class RunningClass {
        init {

            val mObj = TestClass("HI")
            mObj.initiate()
        }
    }
```

If you want to convert part of a file from Java to Kotlin, the easiest way is to copy the code from the Java file in the IDE and paste it into the Kotlin file.

Answer (score 1):

[Kotlin reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/) contains everything<sup>1</sup> you need to know. From there on it's only one step away to the [Kotlin tutorials](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/).

I can only recommend to go through the reference first. There are a lot of interesting concepts that help you write cleaner and simpler code, but you need to know them at least.

You may always want to consult the reference when in doubt and you can play around with [Kotlin Koans online](https://play.kotlinlang.org/koans) to get familiar with some concepts.

So for the questions you asked, you would start from the reference and probably soon (or later ;-)) jump to "Classes and Objects" from there to "Classes and Inheritance" and you arrive at the [constructors](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors) and would have found out yourself rather easily that the answer is:

```
class TestClass(hi: String) {
  init {
    Log.d("check", "Constructor invocation$hi")
  }
  fun initiate() {
    Log.d("check", "Function invocation")
  }
}
```

and:

```
class RunningClass {
  init {
    val mObj = TestClass("HI")
    mObj.initiate()
  }
}
```

<sup>1</sup> if not then you are probably dealing with more advanced stuff... ([KEEP](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP) may or may not be interesting then...)

Answer (score 0):

object of class create

```
class MyClass1 {
companion object Named { }
}

val x = MyClass1  <----object
```

pass data from class parameters

```
class User(var name: String, var age: Int)
```