# Is there a way to convert code from Java to Kotlin in Android Studio without using the copy/paste method?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Usually I have to type the code in Java on notepad then paste it to convert the code.  Is there a button in Android Studio that will let me do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a part of Java source file to Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588117/how-can-i-convert-a-part-of-java-source-file-to-kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

Just use control+alt+shift+k to convert.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me.  I just want to convert the code not an entire file.

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda kotlin has to be in a .kt file, meaning you have to convert the file too, you can't have kotlin in a java file

Answer (score 0):

Select a file, then: Code -> Convert Java File to Kotlin File

[image: In Menu: Code -> Convert Java file to Kotlin File]

Comment: oddly im missing that last option

Comment: Which Android studio version do you use? This menu item appeared in studio version 3.0. In version before 3.0 you need to install Kotlin plugin

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I habited to convert some particular JAVA code to kotlin using [this](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Introduction/Java%20to%20Kotlin%20conversion/Task.kt)

Select convert from java (from the top right side) and paste your JAVA code and convert it.