# In Android Studio, pasting Java code into a Kotlin file doesn't convert to Kotlin anymore

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

When you paste Java code into a Kotlin file in Android Studio, you will get a dialog to convert the Java to Kotlin. When I press "yes" the IDE thinks for a few seconds but nothing happens.

- I tried turning that functionality off and on in the settings.
- I upgraded the Kotlin extension to version 1.3.61.
- I completely reinstalled Android Studio (version 3.5.3).
- I tried removing all the Android Studio directories containing cache and settings.

Nothing helps. Does anybody know how to fix this? I really loved this feature.

Comment: Have you checked that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43308666/2637449

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Wow, it seems like this is the case, thanks! But I think it is still really weird. Because I tried a simple Picasso call which doesn't convert, a very simple switch statement with one case. Doesn't work either. But a SOPLN does work! So did this functionality just got a lot worse then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the IDE it does not convert because its complexity, just try to convert a simple method with a SOPLN and check if it works.

By the way if you want to convert a Java file to a Kotlin one remember that you have the Action of :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be my problem. Although I did try some easy code parts it couldn't convert apparently it was still too complicated... Also weird that Android Studio doesn't show any alert when it couldn't parse/convert the code to Kotlin. Definitely some room for improvement here.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes, it won't work correctly. try `invalidate caches / restart` once.

**Edit:
The online tools has been shutdown**.

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to have a "convert java to kotlin" option. And the Android Development Studio 'Electric Eel 2022' version doen't seem to have it either, although an earlier version would offer to convert pasted code.

Comment: @WeatherVane unfortunately The link has been depreciated.