# Convert Java KeyListener implementation to Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, keylistener, translate, keyevent

I've written the following `KeyListener` in Java.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyHandler implements KeyListener{
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            Global.moveforward=true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            Global.moveback=true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            Global.moveleft=true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            Global.moveright=true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            Global.jump=true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
            Global.sneak=true;
        }
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            Global.moveforward=false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            Global.moveback=false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            Global.moveleft=false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            Global.moveright=false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            Global.jump=false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
            Global.sneak=false;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

How would I best translate this code into Kotlin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a part of Java source file to Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588117/how-can-i-convert-a-part-of-java-source-file-to-kotlin)

Comment: (übrigens: erstens sind auf Stack Overflow eigentlich nur auf Englisch verfasste Fragen erlaubt; zweitens sind [code dumps](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260647/appropriate-response-for-do-my-job-questions) generell off-topic.)

Comment: is this working only inside a GUI?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
Ctrl + Shift + Alt + K (On Windows)
```

Or

```
Command + Option + Shift + K (On Mac)
```

To convert your Java code to Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

**Hello**, if you are using IntelliJ:

You could insert the code into a Kotlin file, and if IntelliJ does not automatically ask you whether it should be converted to Kotlin, select your code and click on "*Convert Java File to Kotlin File*" under the "*Code*" tab.

Now it takes a short time and your code should have been completely converted to Kotlin.

Have fun, I hope I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Code-> Convert Java File to Kotlin File` in IntelliJ.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer I think that function would be useful often for me
Sorry for bad englisch

Answer (score 0):

The translation of the code is (considering enums aren't identical so I assumed `if` conditions as branched with `else if` to clean up):

```kotlin
class KeyHandler : KeyListener {
    override fun keyTyped(e: KeyEvent) {}
    override fun keyPressed(e: KeyEvent) {
        when (e.keyCode) {
            KeyEvent.VK_W -> Global.moveforward = true
            KeyEvent.VK_S -> Global.moveback = true
            KeyEvent.VK_A -> Global.moveleft = true
            KeyEvent.VK_D -> Global.moveright = true
            KeyEvent.VK_SPACE -> Global.jump = true
            KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT -> Global.sneak = true
        }
    }

    override fun keyReleased(e: KeyEvent) {
        when (e.keyCode) {
            KeyEvent.VK_W -> Global.moveforward = false
            KeyEvent.VK_S -> Global.moveback = false
            KeyEvent.VK_A -> Global.moveleft = false
            KeyEvent.VK_D -> Global.moveright = false
            KeyEvent.VK_SPACE -> Global.jump = false
            KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT -> Global.sneak = false
        }
    }
}
```

And whenever you copy paste a Java code in kotlin file (with `.kt` extension), Intellij will prompt you to convert it automatically to Kotlin.

Alternatively you can press `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + K` in your `.java` file to manually convert it to Kotlin.