# Java - Use music playback control buttons

Tags: java, kotlin, audio, system, javasound

Usually on keyboards there is buttons to stop the current track, go to the next track, or to the previous one. When I'm playing sound on YouTube for example, and press the F10 key, the video stops.

I'm creating a Java/Kotlin music player. What currently happens when I have music playing, and then I click F10, is that the last YouTube video I have in an open tab starts playing, and the music player does not get effected at all.

What I want is: When I click F10 (or the other control keys), I want my music player to get affected by them, not YouTube.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Usually you have to make some sort of call to the operating system to setup usage of buttons like that. This isn't something that Java sound handles, you would need to use some other library or something like [tag:jna] to make the appropriate OS calls.

Comment: I think this would depend on the platform/OS. Is this for macOS, Windows, Linux, Android, iOS, a web browser…?

Comment: I want it to run mainly on Ubuntu...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have an application for playing back sound, but when control keys (e.g., F10 in particular) are pressed, your browser is receiving the key, not your application.

If that is the case, the question seems is about [how to use the Swing KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html). The [KeyEvent API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_F10) shows that the keycode for the  key to be `VK_F10`. Are you having problems with implementing this? Kotlin might have it's own way of doing key listening, though. I did find [this SO question on Kotlin KeyListeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62864011/convert-java-keylistener-implementation-to-kotlin).

As far as starting or stopping a sound, that is usually accomplished by wrapping the audio playback class (`Clip` or `SourceDataLine`) in a class that can receive and handle commands to start, stop or continue. Are you having problems with implementing this?

The code that links these two functional areas should be loosely coupled. With that, pursing the two matters as two separate questions will be beneficial.

If your issue is a specific OS implementation question, it would be best to clarify that in the question with additional information.

Comment: I am not using Swing, and not even using GUI. It's a background process. Can I use something else?

Comment: Java GUI toolkits like AWT, Swing & Java-FX do the heavy lifting needed to detect events on the components they put on-screen. Sans them and a focused window they made, the only way to get access to desktop events is via JNA as mentioned in a comment on the question. Note that they might have to try getting this event from a commonly used key, while other apps that act on it have focus. Good luck with all that! You've got your work cut out for you.

Comment: Okay so as I understand, it is not easy to get key events for a background process. But it is doable with JNA.
Thanks @AndrewThompson

Comment: I don't have any experience with making "background processes." My first guess is that in this case the solution will involve writing some sort of KeyListener that only consumes the key you are interested in, and passes all the other key events back to the system. I think this should be readily doable with the Kotlin equivalent of Swing, but that is only an assumption as I haven't done it myself. In any event, I think your best chance of getting help on that is to write a specific question about Kotlin key handling (sans audio tags).