# How to directly read keyboard presses in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, keyboard, jvm

I need a way to read keyboard presses directly, without `readln()` in Kotlin.

For example, I found this on the Kotlin docs:
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/org.w3c.dom.events/-keyboard-event/
But this only works in JavaScript. I am on JVM/native.

If it helps, my application is entirely in the console.

Thanks, ValleyDragon888

**UPDATE: I've tried the RawConsoleInput thing from lukas.j but it finds the class, because when I missed parameters in `read()`, it said `no value passed for read()`, but as soon as I got them right, it says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: RawConsoleInput
        at MainKt.main(Main.kt:5)
        at MainKt.main(Main.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RawConsoleInput
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
        ... 2 more
```

**

**UPDATE 2:** I've added the class, converted to kotlin, and added the JNA with `implementation("net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.14.0")`, and now, loads of classes are missing:
`Native.load`
`LastErrorException`
and also `Operator '===' cannot be applied to 'Long' and 'Int'`

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62864342/17218429 ?

Comment: I have no UI element to assign it to. EDIT: unless its possible to assign one to the terminal?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it

Comment: See my update section.

Comment: There is no built-in way (neither in Java nor in Kotlin). All the answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it use a library. From the error message containing the text 'RawConsoleInput' you probably went for Christian d'Heureuse's answer. In that case you need to install JNA and copy-paste Christian d'Heureuse's RawConsoleInput class (use it as Java code or convert the Java code to Kotlin).

Comment: see the other update section