# How to get Button text using onclicklistner in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am beginner in Android. I am making a joke api app, each button is category.So I need to get button's text content. This is my xml code. I looked at many threads but all were in java

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="science"
    android:onClick="getJoke"
    />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun getJoke(v:View) {
  val b = v as Button
  val buttonText = b.getText().toString()
}
```

Comment: Thank you !. Suppose if no one answered my question here, where should I go find my answer, I tried to search in android documentation but couldn't find it.

Comment: google your question and when you find java answers, there are online converter tools for java into kotlin

Comment: @PatriciaHeimfarth You don't even need to go online for that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39602657

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code only answer.