# Speech to Text using EditText

Tags: android, kotlin, speech

Ok I am building a small app to learn some Speech Recognition in Kotlin. The issue I am experiencing is that my EditText is not posting what is being said. It returns a null value. So when I access the `text.text = result?.get(0).tostring()` it says it has to an Editable!.

I then changed it to `text.append(Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(result?.get(0).toString()))` I have also tried `setText`, `append` and `text.text`

I am not understanding where my code is posting `null` in the editText field of the app. I have the correct permissions in my manifest, here is my code:

`MainActivity`

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity 
import java.util.*

   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val RQ_SPEECH_REC = 102
private lateinit var mic : Button
private lateinit var text : EditText

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    mic = findViewById(R.id.btnMic)
    text = findViewById(R.id.etMain)

    mic.setOnClickListener {
        askSpeechInput()

    }


}

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
@Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == RQ_SPEECH_REC && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        val result = data?.getStringArrayExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS)


        if(text.length() >= 0){
            text.append(text.editableText.toString() + result?.get(0).toString())
        }else{
            text.setText(result?.get(0).toString())
        }


            // text.append(Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(result?.get(0).toString()))

    }
}

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
private fun askSpeechInput() {
    if (!SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Speech is Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }else{
        val i = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault())
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Begin Speaking")
        startActivityForResult(i, RQ_SPEECH_REC)
    }
}
}
```

I am learning the concepts of speech in kotlin. However this app, will be used as a typing source and also voice recognition source to type in the document. I have built numerous Speech in C#, however I wanting to learn Speech in Kotlin to expand my apps and knowledge.I have looked at this for over 3 hours trying different methods. I even used a `TextView` and the same results appear. Any help is greatly appreciated.

also here is the result:

[image: mainview]

[image: speech]

[image: null in edittext]

Comment: It looks like it's setting fine, it's just that `result` is *null*, so when you call `toString()` on it you get `"null"` which is what's being displayed. So you need to work out why you're getting that result in the first place

Comment: @cactustictacs I was following the documentation given by Google, thats how it was explained. From my understanding the EditText returns false as null.. when I put an if statement with if text is null.. it throws an implementation error and says EditText is always false on a null by default.. so it has me stumped. I will look at more indepth tomorrow

Comment: @cactustictacs I have also tried it with just `default?.get(0)` it throws an error, but when I add the `toString()` it doesn't show the error

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "`EditText` returns false as null", you just call `setText` and pass in a `String` (or any `CharSequence`), or you can just use `append` to add your text to whatever's already there (if anything). You don't need to do that `getEditableText` stuff, appending it would just duplicate what's already in there before adding `result` anyway. If you want help with specific errors you'll have to post the stacktrace!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some testing and conversion I finally got the solution. When you are calling the Google Speech you have to place the speech as an `Array`. Then pull the `Array` to the Edit Text. So the code below is the correct way to use the Speech to Text with the sequence of appending new text as well to what is already said. Also I commend @Winston for the pointing in the right direction. I t was not the exact code but it opened my eyes to the right possibility.

`Mainifest`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

`MainActivity.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintMic"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/text_outline"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="Text Goes Here"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        tools:ignore="Autofill" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintMic"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button_mic"
        android:text="Start"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_mic_none_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`MainActivity`

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val RQ_SPEECH_REC = 102
private lateinit var mic : Button
lateinit var text : EditText

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    mic = findViewById(R.id.btnMic)
    text = findViewById(R.id.etMain)

    mic.setOnClickListener {
        askSpeechInput()

    }


}

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
@Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if ((requestCode == RQ_SPEECH_REC) && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null)){


        val res: ArrayList<String> =
            data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS) as ArrayList<String>


        if (text.text.length >= 0)
        {
         text.append(" " + res[0])
        }else {
            text.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(res)[0])
        }


    }
}

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
private fun askSpeechInput() {
    if (!SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Speech is Not Available", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }else{
        val i = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, 
RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault())
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Begin Speaking")
        startActivityForResult(i, RQ_SPEECH_REC)
    }
  }
}
```

With this you can change the UI some and add more features, you can also edit the text and add text by typing, as well with voice.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see this example :

```
  public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    ArrayList data = 
   results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
   float[] confidence = results.getFloatArray(SpeechRecognizer.CONFIDENCE_SCORES);
```

from here : https://gist.github.com/alexschoeberl/d84ce738e353b5e1bd38

Comment: that is for Java and you got to think Kotlin is a bit different. That method works in Java but when I translated it to Kotlin and even using migration java to Kotlin I still get the same results

Comment: this is about how to convert java to Kotlin:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588117/how-can-i-convert-a-part-of-java-source-file-to-kotlin